# Script to read in line, select from value, and print to file

Tags: php

So I have a php script, I want to read in a file line by line, each line only contains one id.  I want to select using sql for each id in the file, then print the result for each selection in the same file.

so far i have:

```
    while (!feof($file))
{
    // Get the current line that the file is reading
    $currentLine = fgets($file) ;
    //explodes integers by amount of sequential spaces
    //$currentLine = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $currentLine);
    echo $currentLine;  //this echo statement prints each line correctly
    selectQuery($currentLine) ;


}   

fclose($file) ;
```

as a test so far i only have

```
 function selectQuery($currentLine){
     echo $currentLine;  //this is undefined?
 }
```

Comment: Unless there's some invisible/unprintable character in `$currentLine`'s name in the selectQuery call, I can't see how this code would fail to echo anything inside the actual function.

Comment: @user570098: Is this all the relevant code? If you can echo the string and right after it you use it as a param of your function it should be working IMO. Also it looks like you are going to do a select query per line, perhaps it is better to consider 'caching' the info you want to query and execute only one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `fgets` is never undefined. However, your approach is way too low-level. Use [`file`](http://php.net/file) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$results = array_filter(file('input.filename'), function(line) {
  return strpos($line, '4') !== false; // Add filter here
});
var_export($results); // Do something with the results here
```